# wpf detect tabtip closed via button (x)

Tags: wpf, keyboard, window, touch

I have an wpf application that runs as desktop app. I integrated the touch keyboard as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601424/after-killing-the-process-for-tabletkeyboardtabtip-exe-application-doesnt-bri). When the keyboard is displayed, my main window gets resized and some elements are just to small, so I want to change my layout when the keyboard is displayed.
The problem is, that I can't detect, when the keyboard is closed by the user with the keyboard close button (X). How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of detecting the close event I detect the size_changed event of my window. The Size of the window changes (~50% smaller) when the keyboard is shown.